# C#: Getter and setter expression for array property

Tags: c#

How can I write the getter and setter expression for array property `CoolerFanIsOn` in the class `CoolerSystem`? I showed the similar desired expression for non-array property `IsOn` of `Lamp` class.

```
class CoolerFan{

    bool isOn;
    public bool IsOn {
        get => isOn;
        set {
            isOn = value;
        }
    }
}

class CoolerSystem {

    private CoolerFan[] = new CoolerFan[5];
    private bool[] coolerFanIsOn = new Boolean[5];

    // invalid code from now

    public bool[] CoolerFanIsOn {
        get => coolerFanIsOn[number];
        set {
            coolerFanIsOn[number] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what your desires are ?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)?

Comment: Why do you have 2 arrays in your class anyway? IMHO, `IsOn` should be a property of the `CoolerFan` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/):

```
public class CoolerSystem
{
    private bool[] _coolerFanIsOn = new Boolean[5];

    public bool this[int index]
    {
        get => _coolerFanIsOn[index];
        set => _coolerFanIsOn[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Btw, the `=>` are [expression bodied properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements) which were new in C#6. If you can't use (setter was new in C#7) use the old syntax, indexers have nothing to do with it(C#3):

```
public bool this[int index]
{
    get { return _coolerFanIsOn[index];  }
    set { _coolerFanIsOn[index] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is supported in C#7 and not C#6.

Comment: Expression bodied properties in C# 6 only applied for getters (setters started in C# 7).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: `String x => "x"; or String x {get;} = "x"` is supported in C#6. I just doubled checked it with C#6 compiler and `String x { get=> "x";}` did not compile saying that '{}' was expected.

Comment: Someone voting down every answer, something wrong? Edited answer to clarify that you dont need expression bodied getters/setters to use indexers.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can write an indexer for your class

```
public bool this[int index]{
   get { return coolerFanIsOn[index]; }
   set { coolerFanIsOn[index] = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you would like to do:

```
class CoolerSystem
{

    private CoolerFan[] _fans = new CoolerFan[5];

    private bool[] _coolerfanIsOn;

    public bool[] CoolerFanIsOn
    {
        get { return _coolerfanIsOn; }
        set
        {
            _coolerfanIsOn = value;
        }
    }

    public bool GetFanState(int number)
    {
        return CoolerFanIsOn[number];
    }

    public void SetFanState(int number, bool value)
    {
        CoolerFanIsOn[number] = value;
    }
}
```